# How to lump sum the number of days of a data of several year?

Tags: r

I have data similar to this. I would like to lump sum the day (I'm not sure the word "lump sum" is correct or not) and create a new column "date" so that new column lump sum the number of 3 years data in ascending order.

```
    year  month day
    2011    1   5
    2011    2   14
    2011    8   21
    2012    2   24
    2012    3   3
    2012    4   4
    2012    5   6
    2013    2   14
    2013    5   17
    2013    6   24
```

I did this code but result was wrong and it's too long also. It doesn't count the February correctly since February has only 28 days. are there any shorter ways?

```
    cday <- function(data,syear=2011,smonth=1,sday=1){
       year <- data[1]
      month <- data[2]
      day <- data[3]
      cmonth <- c(0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31)
      date <- (year-syear)*365+sum(cmonth[1:month])+day
      for(yr in c(syear:year)){
      if(yr==year){
      if(yr%%4==0&&month>2){date<-date+1}
       }else{
         if(yr%%4==0){date<-date+1}
         }
       }
      return(date)
    }
   op10$day.no <- apply(op10[,c("year","month","day")],1,cday)



I expect the result like this:

    year  month day  date
    2011    1   5     5
    2011    1   14    14
    2011    1   21    21
    2011    1   24    24
    2011    2   3     31
    2011    2   4     32
    2011    2   6     34
    2011    2   14    42
    2011    2   17    45
    2011    2   24    52
```

Thank you for helping!!

Comment: Not clear to me. How did your `year` and `month` column changed? How is `date` column calculated?

Comment: Using your data, `your_data$date = with(your_data, as.Date(paste(year, month, day, sep = "-")); your_data$julian_day = as.numeric(format(your_data$date, "%j"))`

Comment: I can't tell from your example if you need it to be cumulative over years. That is, do you want 2012-01-01` to be day 1 again or day 366. If the latter, an easier way would be to just subtract your 0 day, `your_data$result = your_data$date - as.Date("2010-12-31")`

Comment: @Ronak Shak. the date column is the result of summing the days starts from 2011 January 1st

Comment: Dear Gregor. 2012-01-01 is the latter day. until the end of the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Date` classes. Dates and times are complicated, look for tools to do this for you rather than writing your own. Pick whichever of these you want:

```
df$date = with(df, as.Date(paste(year, month, day, sep = "-")))

df$julian_day = as.integer(format(df$date, "%j"))
df$days_since_2010 = as.integer(df$date - as.Date("2010-12-31"))

df
#    year month day       date julian_day days_since_2010
# 1  2011     1   5 2011-01-05          5               5
# 2  2011     2  14 2011-02-14         45              45
# 3  2011     8  21 2011-08-21        233             233
# 4  2012     2  24 2012-02-24         55             420
# 5  2012     3   3 2012-03-03         63             428
# 6  2012     4   4 2012-04-04         95             460
# 7  2012     5   6 2012-05-06        127             492
# 8  2013     2  14 2013-02-14         45             776
# 9  2013     5  17 2013-05-17        137             868
# 10 2013     6  24 2013-06-24        175             906
```

```
# using this data
df = read.table(text = "year  month day
    2011    1   5
    2011    2   14
    2011    8   21
    2012    2   24
    2012    3   3
    2012    4   4
    2012    5   6
    2013    2   14
    2013    5   17
    2013    6   24", header = TRUE)
```

This is all using base R. If you handle dates and times frequently, you may also want to look a the `lubridate` package.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have just tried. But the result is different. In my data, from 2011, January, 24th to 2011, February 3rd there are just 7 days but it counts 10 days.

Comment: There **are** 10 days between those dates. If you want the answer to be 7, then I  guess I completely misunderstood you, and I have no idea what you want. I don't see anything in your sample data or desired output to indicate we're doing anything other than counting calendar days.

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't have ignored Ronak's question. Why do the `year` and `month` columns change as you go from input to output? I assumed you were showing output for a slightly different input, but maybe I was wrong...

Comment: Or are you trying to count business days? Trading days? Something else?

Comment: oh, It was my mistakes. thank you so much for your support!!